# Convert Amazon AMI to Eucalyptus EMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, amazon-ami, eucalyptus

What are the steps to convert an Amazon EBS backed AMI to an Eucalyptus EMI? Can we even do that?
What are the steps to convert an Amazon instance store AMI to an Eucalyptus EMI?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it works for EBS backed AMI, but for instance store AMI that you can download from S3, you can follow the instructions here:

http://open.eucalyptus.com/forum/image-portability-amazon-ami-eucalyptus-emi#comment-10598